# Logging TLS messages in BOTAN

Tags: botan

I have been looking into the the TLS Server/Client/Channel classes to see if they support the logging of structured TLS messages into a file. What I am after is to log all TLS communication for later inspection, debugging and analysis. Any suggestions?